# Users/Roles/Databases Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am fairly new to Postgresql, and this is the situation:

- I have many databases on one instance
- I have many users, each map 1-1 with a database (e.g. Each user can connect to only one database)
- Each user is EITHER Read/Write or Read Only

Now I have figured out how to do this one way, but seems clunky:

- Create a Group Role for each User
- Create a Login Role for each User
- Grant default privileges to Group role on relevant database

However, I'd rather just have one login role for each user, and this role would have a "Type" of READONLY/READ WRITE.  Each user would have these rights on ONLY one database.

Any suggestions how that might be achieved?

Comment: All roles are equal i.e. you could grant privileges to login or non-login ("group") roles.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after writing this out, solved the problem!

- Create Group roles "admin_ro", and "admin_rw"
- Create user roles, as members of one of the above
- Grant "Connect" to user role on individual databases
- Grant the relevant default privileges to the "group role" on the database